# Scraping urls from multiple webpages

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract URLs from multiple webpages (in this case 2) but for some reason, my output is a duplicate list of URLs extracted from the first page. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
# URLs of books in scope
urls = []
for pn in range(2):
    baseUrl = 'https://www.goodreads.com'
    path = '/shelf/show/bestsellers?page='+str(pn+1)
    page = requests.get(baseUrl + path).text
    print(baseUrl+path)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.findAll('a',attrs={'class':"leftAlignedImage"}):
        if link['href'].startswith('/author/show/'):
            pass
        else:
            u=baseUrl+link['href']
            urls.append(u)
for u in urls:
    print(u)
```

Output:

```
https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/bestsellers?page=1
https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/bestsellers?page=2
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5060378-the-girl-who-played-with-fire
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/968.The_Da_Vinci_Code
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4667024-the-help
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2429135.The_Girl_with_the_Dragon_Tattoo
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3.Harry_Potter_and_the_Sorcerer_s_Stone
.
.
.
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4588.Extremely_Loud_Incredibly_Close
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36809135-where-the-crawdads-sing
.
.
.
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4588.Extremely_Loud_Incredibly_Close
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36809135-where-the-crawdads-sing
```

Comment: `attrs={'class':"elementList",'class':"leftAlignedImage"}` this looks fishy. Python dict cannot contain same keys.

Comment: Both times you're getting the same page. the `page=2` URL parameter doesn't do anything and just loads the same page.

Comment: @AndrejKesely that's not the issue but you are right I forgot to get rid of the first class, just edited it. Still the issue is that even though requests is getting another URL in the second loop it's still working with the first URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting duplicate URLs because both times you are loading the same page. That website shows **only the first page** of best-sellers if you are **not logged in**, even if you set `page=2`.

To fix this, you will have to either modify your code to login first before loading the pages, or to pass cookies that you have to import from a logged-in browser.

Comment: Good catch! Didn't realize only the first page was displayed when not logged in. I'll look into it.